# c# , Visual studio, pas variable to external class and check/do action

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, variables

I am a newbie at this, so please be kind.

My question is maybe simple for trained programmers but I am not, so here go's.

I have a variable with a value. The value I want to check in a external class.
According to which value there is will be a action also in the external class

So in form1.cs I have a string value and in checkval.cs and want to handle the string value.

Is there a best way to do this?

many thanks for your answers
martinus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating Data In A WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109350/validating-data-in-a-winform)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on the value as a parameter to the class like

```
checkval classvar = new checkval(parameter)
```

Or you can make sure `checkval.cs` and `form1.cs` are in the same namespace, if they are you can then use public variables across them.

Comment: Hi DaanV,

Thanks for your answer, i get it now and solved my problem.