# How do I get the programme to allow the user to change info if it is enterred incorrectly during a loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops, if-statement

I am writing a programme that allows a user to enter personal details but each detail is limited by character length or something like that. I need it to allow the user to enter the details wrong 5 time before being cleared and sent back to a previous form. Im currently trying to use a loop for this but at the moment when you press the enter details button it just loops 5 times straight away and sends the user back without the user being able to change details and try again. Here is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
        'Declare variables 
        'This is the form that i will only allow the operator to enter 5 mistakes before being locked out

        Dim strStreetAddress As String = txtStreetAddress.Text
        Dim strTown As String = txtTown.Text
        Dim strCounty As String = txtCounty.Text
        Dim strEircode As String = txtEircode.Text
        Dim mskPhoneNumber As String = mskNumber.Text
        Dim intErrorCount As Integer = 0




        'set up if statements 

        Do Until intErrorCount = 5
            If strStreetAddress.Length = 0 Or strTown.Length = 0 Or strCounty.Length = 0 Or mskPhoneNumber.Length = 0 Or strEircode.Length = 0 Then
                intErrorCount += 1
                MessageBox.Show("One or more details have not been enterred")
                txtStreetAddress.Clear()
                txtCounty.Clear()
                txtEircode.Clear()
                txtTown.Clear()
                mskNumber.Clear()



            ElseIf strStreetAddress.Length > 50 Or strTown.Length > 15 Or strCounty.Length > 10 Or strEircode.Length <> 7 Or mskPhoneNumber.Length <> 10 Then
                intErrorCount += 1
                MessageBox.Show("One or more detais has been entered incorrectly")
                txtStreetAddress.Clear()
                txtCounty.Clear()
                txtEircode.Clear()
                txtTown.Clear()
                mskNumber.Clear()




            Else MessageBox.Show("All Details Entered Correctly")
                Me.Hide()
                frmPurchaseScreen.Show()
            End If
        Loop

        'if errorcount reaches 5 then operator must login again and restart
        If intErrorCount = 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You have made too many errors, you must Login again")
            Me.Hide()
            frmLogin.Show()

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtErrorCount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtErrorCount.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you limit error inputs to 5 times? There is a validation concept in WinForms. Find An example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109350/validating-data-in-a-winform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you declare your error counter **inside** the sub and because the user can't change his input when you loop.

If you declare a variable in a sub, it will disappear as soon as the code exits the sub. To keep information outside of a sub, you need to declare the variable at a higher level.

Don't loop inside the sub called when the user click and remember the errors number with a higher level variable :

```
 Private intErrorCount As Integer = 0

    Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Declare variables 
        'This is the form that i will only allow the operator to enter 5 mistakes before being locked out

        Dim strStreetAddress As String = txtStreetAddress.Text
        Dim strTown As String = txtTown.Text
        Dim strCounty As String = txtCounty.Text
        Dim strEircode As String = txtEircode.Text
        Dim mskPhoneNumber As String = mskNumber.Text





        If strStreetAddress.Length = 0 Or strTown.Length = 0 Or strCounty.Length = 0 Or mskPhoneNumber.Length = 0 Or strEircode.Length = 0 Then
            intErrorCount += 1
            MessageBox.Show("One or more details have not been enterred")
            txtStreetAddress.Clear()
            txtCounty.Clear()
            txtEircode.Clear()
            txtTown.Clear()
            mskNumber.Clear()



        ElseIf strStreetAddress.Length > 50 Or strTown.Length > 15 Or strCounty.Length > 10 Or strEircode.Length <> 7 Or mskPhoneNumber.Length <> 10 Then
            intErrorCount += 1
            MessageBox.Show("One or more detais has been entered incorrectly")
            txtStreetAddress.Clear()
            txtCounty.Clear()
            txtEircode.Clear()
            txtTown.Clear()
            mskNumber.Clear()




        Else MessageBox.Show("All Details Entered Correctly")
            Me.Hide()
            frmPurchaseScreen.Show()
        End If


        'if errorcount reaches 5 then operator must login again and restart
        If intErrorCount = 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You have made too many errors, you must Login again")
            Me.Hide()
            frmLogin.Show()

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: You are a life saver! I've been trying so many different things cant believe it was so simple. Thank You!

Comment: I'm glad to help you :) I guess it's because you were doing console app before. With winform, you have to think in terms of events.